# JSon to Asp.Net inside a Web Worker. Can't find the method inside the Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, web-worker

I'm sending a JSon to my Asp.Net MVC 3 Controller that is inside a Web Worker (using jquery-hive).
At the PostMessage, I can capture a Asp.Net error telling me that it find the controller but has no action method X.

See the code:
Here I call the Worker at main.js:

```
 var worker = new Worker('models/worker.js');

worker.onmessage = function (event) {
    var a = event;
};
worker.postMessage(null);
```

The code into worker.js:

```
  importScripts('hive.pollen.js');  $(function (msg) {
    $.ajax.get({
        url: '/Search/Method1/',
        dataType: 'POST',
        data: null,
        success: function (jsonObj) {
            $.send( jsonObj);
                }
    });
});
```

The controller has this method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Method1(string test)
    {
        return Json("worked! " + test);
    }
```

The posMessage that the worker give me back, it's a asp.net error.

> [HttpException]: A public action method "Method1" was not found on controller SearchController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are issuing a GET request ($.ajax.get method).
Try using jquery's $.post()

Comment: You can also change [HttpPost] to [HttpGet]. Also, beware of the string inside the Json method. AFAIK, Json is supposed to encode arrays or objects (which will contain values or properties, respectively). Not sure if it is standard or possible to Json encode a string.

Comment: You're right Marcelo. I don't know why the hell I thought that jquery-hive do not implement the $.post. Working like a charm! Tks

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on: `dataType: 'POST'`.

In your case, you have to put `dataType: 'json'` in order to send the data in the correct format